# Expansion of a distribution in terms of marginals and moments

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $f(x,y) \in \mathcal{L}^2(\mathbb{R^2})$ be a probability density function (PDF).

Is there any way to expand $f(x,y)$ in terms of its marginals $\int f(x,y) dx, \int f(x,y)dy$ and its moments $\int x^n f(x,y) dx, \int y^n f(x,y) dy, \int x^n y^m f(x,y)$?

I know that knowledge of the marginals is not enough to recover the joint PDF but I don't know whether the additional knowledge of the moments can help. Thus, I was wondering if there is some analog of the Taylor expansion for joint PDFs in terms of its marginals and moments.

Comment: There is a distinction between distribution functions and density functions. It appears that you are really talking about densities. Further, $f(x,y)\in\mathcal L ^{2}(\mathbb R)$ doesn't make sense. Two dimensional densities are non-negative measurable functions which integrate to $1$ and they may not be square integrable. Conversely, square integrable functions may not be intergable.

Comment: Why it would not make sense ? It is just another constraint on the density. I do not know if it is usefull for the problem stated though. @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: @nicomezi I am not saying that a density function cannot be square integrable, but the very first sentence in the question is confusing. OP should at least clarify whether he is talking about distributions or densities.

Comment: If $f$ is defined on $\mathbb R^2$, what can the condition that $f$ is square integrable on $\mathbb R$, mean?

Comment: Did Sorry, it is a typo, I just corrected it. @KaviRamaMurthy Sorry for the confusion, I am talking about densities, I also corrected it